# Scenekit - vector/tangent displacement map

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit

Important: please note that this question is about VECTOR map. Not height map.

I'm trying to implement Vector displacement in Scenekit, as described on apple presentation:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uli814Qugm8&app=desktop

[Apple presentation on Scenekit vector displacement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY8ll.png)

My code is:

```
    material?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "\(materialFilePrefix)-albedo.jpg")
```

material?.displacement.contents = UIImage(named: "(materialFilePrefix)-displacement.exr")
  material?.displacement.textureComponents = .all

My Xcode project:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewKGL.jpg)

But I don't get the displacement... Anything wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

From checking out SCNMaterial’s header and the presentation, it looks like you might need to enable tessellation on your node’s geometry for displacement to work. That’d look like this:

```
let tessellator = SCNGeometryTesselator()
tessellator.edgeTessellationFactor = 2 // may not need this line (default is 1), or may need to set it higher to get a smooth result
tessellator.edgeTessellationFactor = 2 // ditto
sphereNode.geometry?.tessellator = tessellator
```

Comment: Thanks for helping Noah! : )

I added your code, but still no ear vector displacement...    : /
https://gyazo.com/a3e77ba259941cdc226e5f6baaa0626e

Here is my project Setup:
https://gyazo.com/7052ab77f76d1c74a9787c279ae2b774

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Oh, I just realized something—it may not work in the iOS simulator, since tessellation requires Metal and the simulator doesn’t have that available. Can you try it on a device?

Comment: Yep, simulator doesn’t work for this.  But I’m trying on device (iPhone 7). All maps work great, except for the vector displacement exr

Comment: Additional info: I know iPhone 7 doesn’t have enough hardware for the exr vector displacement file... but the displacement is NOT being applied, because the app is installed and all the maps are there, except vector.                  Ex: when I try an exr height map, iPhone app crashes (says it doesn’t have sufficient memory) which indicates that the exr map was deployed.